# Can we integrate keycloak to add security to a asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, keycloak

As part of a project we have integrated keycloak with our .net core application, but we have a legacy system which is a  asp.net web application, It have its own login screen whenever a user logs in it should fetch the username and password and validate against Keycloak.

The approach we are trying to do is.

- 1.Fetch all users from Keycloak on a specific realm
- 2.Parse the json and find whether the specifc username and password exist in that json array.

Is this way of giving authentication is correct?

Need some suggestion!!!

Comment: If the json is passed anywhere near the client or browser, this is extremely insecure. The json is plain text and is trivial to get access to if it is exposed to the browser. You would then have usernames and passwords exposed to a potential hacker. It is trivial to get access to any json response sent to a browser.

Comment: Better way ,you can use keycloak Login screen to your web-app its quite simple & easy. Look and feel of login screens can be updated from `*.ftl` file also by updating  **css** files.

Comment: Do you have the current credentials stored in a database (login and hashed password)? If yes, you could create a provider to connect from keycloak: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_user-storage-federation Once done, use the OpenId connect flows to securely handle authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at their basic authentication example...

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/basic-auth

As stated in the comments.  Returning JSON with all of the username and passwords is NOT secure, hashed/salted/or not, it doesn't matter.